# Regular Expression to extract last 4 numeric digits

Tags: regex, jmeter

I jmeter i need to extract last 4 digit of the response

Example

Response:
16789006328208"}}

I need to extract 8208
My right boundary is dynamic and left boundary "}} is constant

Please provide suggestions

Comment: There are a few flavors of Regex in the future please include what language you are using regex with.

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

`(\d{4})"`

Note that your value will be in your first capturing group.

See my work sheet here.

**https://regex101.com/r/G4ROyi/1**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Regular Expression:

```
(\d{4})"}}
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

regexp_substr(regexp_replace(string,'\D'),'\d{0,4}$')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).